# SQL query AdventureWorksDw2012 find orders containing two products

Tags: sql, adventureworks

Hello i was hoping someone can aid with a query on adventurworks2012 db,

I am trying to find all the orders where a customer has purchased the exact same two items.

e.g.

```
select p.* 
from FactInternetSales f
inner join DimProduct p on p.ProductKey = f.ProductKey
where  ProductAlternateKey in ('BK-M18B-40','TI-M267')
```

example SalesOrderNumber that contains both: SO58845

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an inner join on a sub-select for one productAlternateKey and then just simply look for the other productAlternateKey in the original Where clasue.

Example script (not tested):

```
select p.*
from FactInternetSales f
inner join DimProduct p on p.ProductKey = f.ProductKey
inner join (select p2.*
            from FactInternetSales f2
            inner join DimProduct p2 on p2.ProductKey = f2.ProductKey
            where  ProductAlternateKey = 'TI-M267') innerSelect on p.ProdctKey = innerselect.ProductKey
where  ProductAlternateKey ='BK-M18B-40'
```

Comment: I believe I used intersect for this too